Ajustar cor de fundo no MudListItem - Blazor & MudBlazor
Ola, Quando estou colocando a cor de fundo no MudListItem a cor fica fora do padrao como mostro.
Sou novo nao consigo mandar imagem por isso esta via link para visualizar
Meu codigo
 <MudPaper Class="rounded-xl">
     <MudList  Style="rounded-xl" Clickable="false" Dense="true">
         <MudListItem Style="background-color: #F5F4F4;">
             <MudText>Instruções para a transferência bancária</MudText>
         </MudListItem>
         <MudDivider />
         <MudListItem>
             <MudText Typo="Typo.caption">NÃO E POSSÍVEL PAGAR NO CHECK-IN !!!</MudText>
             <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" GutterBottom="true" Class="ml-auto">
                 Reservas não paga no período de  20 minutos sera cancelada, como nossos Termos e Politicas.
                 Pix nossa chave CNPJ  
                 Nome  
                 Banco SICOOB
                 Reservas também sem CPF serão canceladas.
             </MudText>
         </MudListItem>
     </MudList>
 </MudPaper>

Try Mudblazor

 <MudPaper  Class="rounded-xl">
     <MudListItem style="background-color: #F5F4F4;" class="rounded-t-xl" >
             <MudText >Instruções para a transferência bancária</MudText>
         </MudListItem>
         <MudDivider />
      <MudListItem >
             <MudText Typo="Typo.caption">NÃO E POSSÍVEL PAGAR NO CHECK-IN !!!</MudText>
             <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" GutterBottom="true" Class="ml-auto">
                 Reservas não paga no período de  20 minutos sera cancelada, como nossos Termos e Politicas.
                 Pix nossa chave CNPJ 35.337.342/0001-86
                 Nome JOSE CARLOS NOBRE
                 Banco SICOOB
                 Reservas também sem CPF serão canceladas.
             </MudText>
         </MudListItem>
 
 </MudPaper>

